# Is it portable to remove FD_CLOEXEC from shm_open() fd?

Tags: unix, exec, posix, shared-memory

The following technique passes shared memory from a parent process to its child process via a file descriptor inherited by the child over exec.

How portable is it across different Unix-like operating systems?

**Parent process:**

```
fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600);
shm_unlink(name);
flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD);
flags &= ~FD_CLOEXEC;  // Clear the close-on-exec flag.
fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, flags);
ftruncate(fd, (off_t)size);
buf = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

**Child process started by parent using fork and exec:**

```
fstat(fd, &st);  // fd is known file descriptor number from parent process.
size = st.st_size;
buf = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

The POSIX [`shm_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/shm_open.html) specification says:

> The FD_CLOEXEC file descriptor flag associated with the new file descriptor is set.

But it doesn't say anything about whether it is permissible or effective to manually remove that flag using `fcntl()`.

I was able to make it work on MacOS but does this work more generally? What about Linux, *BSD and Solaris?

Comment: I wrote an example program and was able to make it work on MacOS, Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFlyBSD. The `shm_open()` name argument is not trivial to use portably though.